# What's the best method for bracing a list of aligned equations?

Tags: equations, best-practices, nesting

I would like to reduce the height of the `\left\{` in the following, to make it the same height as the equations:

```
%\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{align*}
\mathcal L&= - 0.75 w(S) - 0.25 w(F) + \lambda \big(\ln(256) -3\ln(w(S)) - \ln(w(F)) \big)\\ 
&\hspace{10mm}+ \mu\big(\ln(16) - \ln(w(S)) + \ln(w(F))\big)\\[1ex]
&\left\{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{
\begin{flalign}
0=\diffp{\mathcal L}{{w(S)}} &= -0.75 -\frac{3\lambda}{w(S)} - \frac\mu{w(S)}\\
0=\diffp{\mathcal L}{{w(F)}} &= -0.25 - \frac\lambda{w(F)} + \frac\mu{w(F)}&
\end{flalign}}\right.
\end{align*}
```

I wanted to use `flalign` as opposed to `array` to make it easy to get the fractions in `\displaystyle`. I understand that with `\begin{array}{rllrl}`*, I would have to use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`, and I would want to adjust `\arraycolsep`, because I don't like the big gap before the `=` sign in the `array` environment in this situation. You're welcome to suggest an improvement to my code!

*Generally, with derivatives of a Lagrangian, I would use the third `l` for an `\implies` sign, followed by a simplification of the equation.

Comment: you can (should) use one of the ams in-equation alignments such as `aligned` rather than nest a parbox with `flalign`  `algned`, `split` etc all use display math. (but do you need the equation numbering?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I like your answer, as it is simple. I don't always need the equation numbering - but I could just `tag` the equations if I do. You're welcome to tell me a more complete list of the available in-equation environments, or where to find that information.

Comment: `texdoc amsmath`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it isn't easy to find that information in amsmath.pdf, because that document seems to just be about how the package is written, and the available environments for nesting aren't all in one place.

Comment: `texdoc amsmath` should show you amslguide.pdf (the user guide) not amsmath.pdf (the source code of the package), if not try texdoc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `tag` doesn't work in `aligned`. How can I number the equations please?

Comment: that's why I asked if you needed numbers... empheq as in the accepted answer is probably your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it is the best method, but I suggest using `empheq` (needless to load `amsmath`) and `linegoal`. The latter package calculates the remaining width at the current point on the line (requires 2 compilations):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathcal L&= - 0.75 w(S) - 0.25 w(F) + \lambda \big(\ln(256) -3\ln(w(S)) - \ln(w(F)) \big)\\
&\hspace{10mm}+ \mu\big(\ln(16) - \ln(w(S)) + \ln(w(F))\big)\\[1ex]
&\parbox{1\linegoal}{
\begin{empheq}[left =\empheqlbrace]{flalign}
0=\diffp{\mathcal L}{{w(S)}} &= -0.75 -\frac{3\lambda}{w(S)} - \frac\mu{w(S)}\\
0=\diffp{\mathcal L}{{w(F)}} &= -0.25 - \frac\lambda{w(F)} + \frac\mu{w(F)}&
\end{empheq}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basing the height of `\left\{` on an invisible vertical line will give you control over its height:

```
... &\left\{\rule{0pt}{6.6ex}\right.\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{
\begin{flalign*} ...
```